# Cursor freezing during start up

Tags: cursor

I have Ubuntu 12.04 pre installed on an hp laptop. The cursor has been freezing periodically for a while now but now it does it every time I start up.

It moves when I login but as soon as I get to my home screen it freezes and I can't get any further.

Help! I'm not a techie but love ubuntu...

Comment: Is your system updated? Also, 12.04 support ends in a few months. Please test a 16.04 live session. If it work fine then backup and install 16.04 from scratch.

Comment: If you hardware is old and you have performance issues with 16.04 you might be happier with 14.04 which runs faster for many.

Comment: The laptop is about 18 months old . I have been doing updates.  How do I upgrade my ububtu to 14.04 or 16.04 and will I lose any work on my hard drive?

Comment: Ah just tried logging in as a guest and the mouse worked, so guessing it is one of my apps that is killing it. Still don't know what to do as I need files on my hard drive. ..